# People are so involved in/on/with social media

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

Which ones are correct, and among the correct ones, how does each convey the meaning and differ from others?

> 1 These days, people are so involved in social media.

> 2 These days, people are so involved on social media.

> 3 These days, people are so involved with social media.

Comment: Have you searched online for an answer?

Comment: Yes. They mostly talk about in or on social media in a general sense (for example https://www.quora.com/Which-is-grammatically-correct-in-social-media-or-on-social-media). My question is specifically about involvement.

Comment: Did you use parentheses "involved in" "involved on" "involved with"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=involved%20with%20social%20media%2Cinvolved%20in%20social%20media%2Cinvolved%20on%20social%20media&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinvolved%20with%20social%20media%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvolved%20in%20social%20media%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvolved%20on%20social%20media%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cinvolved%20with%20social%20media%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvolved%20in%20social%20media%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvolved%20on%20social%20media%3B%2Cc1) shows that "involved in social media" is the most widely used and "involved on social media" the least.

We generally use "involved in" and "involved with" interchangeably, to express complicity, participation, and interest.

"involved in" can also be used to express concentration, to the exclusion of other things (so involved in my project that I didn't hear the doorbell).

"involved with" can also be used to describe being in a relationship with somebody.

In general usage, we would only use "involved on" when "on" is the normal preposition, for example "on a committee" or "on campus". In my opinion, "On social media" relates to posts, rather than to the people who are posting or reading, however actual references in the Ngram graph do relate to people.